# COALESCE and NULLIF with aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

After following every thread I could find on this and not getting it to work I would love to get some input on what I might be doing wrong. I am aggregating a number of int2 fields using Coalesce. I only get values when every field has values; if there is a null value anywhere (and that's common), the result of the whole aggregation is null. I know the nullif() function can replace nulls with a usable value like 0, but whatever I do I either get an error, or 0 as the result of the entire aggregation. Any help appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
SELECT
"public".jam_fodder_productivity.cows,
"public".jam_fodder_productivity.sheep,
"public".jam_fodder_productivity.lamb,
"public".jam_fodder_productivity.horse,
"public".jam_fodder_productivity.ungneyti,
COALESCE(jam_fodder_productivity.cows + (jam_fodder_productivity.ungneyti / 2::double precision) + (jam_fodder_productivity.horse / 2::double precision) + (jam_fodder_productivity.sheep / 6::double precision) + (jam_fodder_productivity.lamb / 12::double precision)) AS total_productivity
FROM
"public".jam_fodder_productivity
```

The result of the query looks like this:

[coalesce result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpWpY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to apply

```
COALESCE(<expression>, 0)
```

to each of the expressions that make up the sum.

Otherwise, if any of the expressions is NULL, the whole sum becomes NULL.

So the entry would be calculated as

```
COALESCE(jam_fodder_productivity.cows, 0)
+ COALESCE(jam_fodder_productivity.ungneyti / 2::double precision, 0)
+ COALESCE(jam_fodder_productivity.horse / 2::double precision, 0)
+ COALESCE(jam_fodder_productivity.sheep / 6::double precision, 0)
+ COALESCE(jam_fodder_productivity.lamb / 12::double precision, 0)
   AS total_productivity
```

Comment: Works like a charm @Laurenz Albe! Thanks for the knowledge.